# Proof of a property of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I'm new here and this is my first question.

I'm struggling with a proof for my statistics course.

I need to show the following proposition:

$E[Y^2|\bar{X}=\bar{x}]\geq[E(Y|\bar{X}=\bar{x})]^2$

I tried to show it using Jensen's inequality but my teacher told me that is not correct.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- This can be shown using $\textrm{Var}(Y \mid \bar X = \bar x) \ge 0$
- So if you want more detail, expand and rearrange  $\mathbb E[(Y - \mathbb E[Y \mid \bar X = \bar x])^2 \mid \bar X = \bar x] \ge 0$, which is true since  it is the conditional expectation of a square term

Answer (score 1):

Not to subvert your teacher, but there is a conditional form of Jensen's inquality, which in your situation would be: For a function $g$ defined and convex on the range of $Y$,
$$
E[g(Y)\mid \bar X =\bar x]\ge g\left(E[Y\mid \bar X = \bar x]\right).
$$
(Of course, $Y$ needs to have a finite expectation.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know where can I find a proof of this inequality?

Comment: @FedericoCastelloRojo Conditional expectation is an expectation, so I think the usual Jensen's inequality applies in this case. To prove the usual Jensen's inequality, Taylor expand $$g(Y) = g(E(Y)) + g'(E(Y))(Y - E(Y)) + \frac{g''(\xi(E(Y), Y))}{2}(Y - E(Y))^2 \geq g(E(Y)) + g'(E(Y))(Y - E(Y)),$$ then take expectations of both sides.